# How to apply an openGL filter effect to one texture and save it

Tags: android, ios, delphi, opengl-es, firemonkey

I m under Delphi and I would like to offer to end user the ability correct a little their picture (`light, contrast, color, etc`) before uploading them in the app. Visually this is quite easy to do with `TfilterEffect` component (**openGL filter**), however how to **save the resulting picture** ? I need to save in the same size as the original picture, so screen capture can't work

Also is their any libraries that work under IOS and Android that help to do this ?

Comment: "Also is their any libraries that work under IOS and Android that help to do this?" Highly unlikely. The two platforms have different OS's and use different languages. OpenGL pretty close to the hardware and fussy to set up, so the details of getting it to work are likely to be different for each platform.

Comment: thanks @DuncanC ... i was thinking about a library to update the light, contrast, color, etc. of the picture in a generic way, with ou without openGL

Comment: For iOS you might look at Core Image filters. There are filters for brightness and contrast, as well as various color adjustment filters. The most powerful one appears to be one called Color Cube, but its' not very well documented and pretty complex to use.

Comment: You're most likely applying effects to an intermediate bitmap. If so, save that bitmap.

Comment: How to apply effect to an intermediate bitmap? as far as i know i apply filter to an texture not a bitmap